# In what order Should I read the Marvel story arcs between Civil War and Avengers vs. X-Men?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order

I just read Civil War and want to read the arcs between that and Avengers Vs X-Men.
So far I have:

1. Civil War
2. Secret Invasion
3. House of M
4. Avengers Disassembled
5. Dark Avengers
6. ???
7. AvX

I'm pretty sure something happened between Dark Avengers and AvX but it gets foggy.
Can someone help me fill in the blanks/re-order the major story arcs?

I'm mostly interested in Avengers/X-Men stories. I know there are side stories to each of the major arcs and I'll fill in the blanks as I get to them, but what are the major titles to look for in TPB form?

Comment: Of interest: http://www.comicbookherald.com/the-complete-marvel-reading-order-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I found my answer on Wikipedia: From the article on [Avengers Disassembled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_Disassembled)

> The event is now considered by Marvel editors as the first part of a
>   long series of events, which includes House of M, Decimation, Planet
>   Hulk, Civil War, The Initiative, Endangered Species, World War Hulk,
>   Messiah Complex, Divided We Stand, Secret Invasion, Manifest Destiny,
>   Dark Reign, Messiah War, Utopia, Nation X and Necrosha . All these
>   grim events lead up to Siege written by Brian Michael Bendis in 2010,
>   which ushers in a new Heroic Age for Marvel, and X-Men: Second Coming
>   by Christopher Yost and Craig Kyle, which sees the slow rebirth of
>   Earth's Mutant population.

Answer (score 1):

The timeline of Marvel's biggest company wide cross over events goes as followed
1. Disassembled: Scarlet Witch goes crazy causes havoc across the marvel universe 
2. House of M: Scarlet Witch creates a new reality with mutants as the majority of humanity
3. Civil War: a civil war between all the heroes. 
4. Secret Invasion: Skrulls have replaced some of the heroes are taking over Earth from within. 
5. Siege: Norman Osborne has taken over offer the Invasion and created the Dark Avengers. Siege is the good Averagers finally coming together after Civil War. (Important to know, between events Captain America comes back, Iron Man goes into a comma to save everyone from Norman, Asgard is put on earth)
6. Fear Itself: Red Skull's daughter unleashes evil Asgard power. 
7. AvX: Avengers and X-Men fight over the return of the Phoenix. 
There were also many subevents in this time but they were mostly contained to a single title and are not that important to the main thread of Marvel's events.

Comment: You're kind of off. And Dark Avengers is not a Crossover event, it's just a plain title to its own series.
Anyhow, the order after Civil War goes:
1. World War Hulk.
2. Annihilation Conquest.
3. Messiah Complex.
4. Secret Invasion.
5. Messiah War.
6. Utopia.
7. Necrosha.
8. Siege.
9. Second Coming.
10. World War Hulks.